# How to filter a specific colour with AForge

Tags: c#, colors, filtering, rgb, aforge

Im working with the library AForge and trying to change for example all green and yellow pixel to white. But red pixels should remain the same. I tried out some things but unfortunately didnt get it.
I use EuclideanColorFiltering class to filter a bitmap object, but however I choose CenterColor and Radius, I dont reach my goal.
Can somebody try to explain how this filtering works?

Answer (score 0):

There are getpixel and setpixel way .
but for fast process you should use lockbit and get the Scan0 in a pointer

after lockbit you can access all of your bitmap bytes and colors
for example you can read the red pixels from your bitmap like this

```
    IntPtr Iptr = bitmapData.Scan0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i<frame.Height; i++)
    {
       for(int j = 0 ; j < frame.Width ; j++)
       {
         int index = ((i * frame.Width) + j) * 
                    (Bitmap.GetPixelFormatSize(frame.PixelFormat)/8);
         byte red = Marshal.ReadByte(Iptr + index + 2 ) ; 
         byte green= Marshal.ReadByte(Iptr + index +1);
         byte blue= Marshal.ReadByte(Iptr + index );
          // Also after get the colors you can Use marshal.writebyte to set the pixel your own color
         }
        }
```